Custom QGIS plugin repository on a local server
To make it easier to manage updates to company specific plugins I am trying to setup a custom plugin repository on our file server.
I have found some helpful documentation but can't get it to work.
This post is good but following the plgins.xml template doesn't work for me.
This article is a bit more detailed but doesn't deal with hosting on a local file server.
From the plugin manager I get a successful connection to the repo using the URL format as below
file:\\somecompany-fps\Shared\GIS Resource\PluginRepo\plugins.xml


My xml file looks something like the below and this is where I think the issue lies:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="AcadScript" version="0.1">
        <description>This plugin does magic</description>
        <qgis_minimum_version>2.2</qgis_minimum_version>
        <file_name>AcadScript.0.1</file_name>
        <author_name>Me</author_name>
        <download_url>"file:\\somecompany-fps\Shared\GIS Resource\PluginRepo\AcadScript.0.1.zip"</download_url>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>

I have tested the plugin installs via zip file and that works fine.

The download_url needs to be file:// protocol + full path with forward slashes and with no " " double quotes.
So if your path is \\somecompany-fps\Shared\GIS Resource\PluginRepo\AcadScript.0.1.zip, your URL should be file:////somecompany-fps/Shared/GIS Resource/PluginRepo/AcadScript.0.1.zip.  Note: you may need to experiment with the number of slashes between file:// and the UNC server path, as I don't have a Windows/Samba server available to test.
Also, remove version from file_name and the actual plugin folder before you zip it, i.e. name the plugin folder AcadScript, zip it and rename the zipfile AcadScript.0.1.zip.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="AcadScript" version="0.1">
        <description>This plugin does magic</description>
        <qgis_minimum_version>2.2</qgis_minimum_version>
        <file_name>AcadScript</file_name>
        <author_name>Me</author_name>
        <download_url>file:////somecompany-fps/Shared/GIS Resource/PluginRepo/AcadScript.0.1.zip</download_url>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>

As an example, just on my local filesystem (Linux):
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="Test" version="0.1">
        <description>This plugin does stuff</description>
        <qgis_minimum_version>3.0</qgis_minimum_version>
        <file_name>Test</file_name>
        <author_name>Me</author_name>
        <download_url>file:///home/user/Test-0.1.zip</download_url>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>




I have made the changes to the zip contents and to the XML and the plugin still doesn't show up - your instructions look careful enough to be right so I guess its a file path issue. file:// works for finding the XML and if I paste the path into explorer but I have tried /// and //// with no joy

Tried file://somecompany-fps/Shared/GIS Resource/PluginRepo/AcadScript.0.1.zip as well? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Number_of_slash_characters

yep tried 1-4 /

I have also tried with the zip file in an AWS bucket

Path without spaces? Replace space with %20?

I tried moving it to a folder without spaces in the name, still no joy

I re-visited this on a different system and the instructions in the answer work, so I suspect it was an issue with QGIS version of the network file server/ path
